# Handling Ruby Errors with multiple methods that must be executed if one fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, channel, error-logging

I've inherited a codebase where they have a call method to send out a document via multiple channels - FTP, SMS, and an Email service.

The way its currently set up is that if the email distribution fails, it will exit out of the method and ensure the other channels run. There currently seems to be very basic error handling and thats about it.

I need it to log an error then move on to the following methods -- without hopefully rewriting all the existing code

How can I go about doing this? Will the following work?

the main call method:

```
def call
  add_customers_to_statement_distribution

  statement.final!

  copy_generated_pdf_to_final_version

  copy_detailed_csv_to_final_version

  copy_png_thumbnails_with_days_key_to_public_storage

  copy_statement_to_public_storage

  disribute_statement_by_email

  DistributeToFTP.call(statement)

  NotifyCustomersBySms.call(statement)
end
```

The method with my possible rescue statement added in:

```
def distribute_statement_by_email
  DistributeStatementByEmail.call(statement_distribution, 
                                  SENDER_EMAIL, 
                                  final_customers_with_csv, 
                                  with_csv: true)

  DistributeStatementByEmail.call(statement_distribution, 
                                  SENDER_EMAIL, 
                                  final_customers_without_csv, 
                                  with_csv: false)

rescue StandardDistributionError => error
  error.new("Statement distributed by email has raised an issue: "\
              "#{error.message}")
end
```

I want to make sure I handle the error in a graceful way.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but what's your question?

Comment: Sorry about that ---     in the call method if the disribute_statement_by_email fails, the following methods are not executed.   Id like to just log an error and ensure the following methods are executed despite an error in another method (mainly the email method). Not too sure what the best way to go about that is.

Comment: You could of course put the statements in a method, returning where appropriate. For exampple: `def meth(*args); <do taske 1>; return if <condition 1>; <do task 2>; return if <condition 2>; <do task 3>; return if <condition 3>; end`.